# How to get an output variable with double indexing to work with parfor?

Tags: matlab, parallel-processing

I'm using Matlab for my studies for a while now, and would like to learn more about parallel computing. Parfor seems like a very useful technique. I can't get it to work with the following code:

```
resultsOfRW = ones(100,N);

parfor i= 1:100

   RWs{i} = A; %I want to modify A in every iteration

   j = 1;
   S = 2; %just something larger than 1

   while j <= N && S > 1
        RWs{i} = DoSomethingRandomly(RWs{i}); % Make some (stochastic) change to RWs{i}
        S = GetSomeResultFrom(RWs{i});

        resultOfRW(i,j) = S; %This is invalid

        j = j+1;
   end
end
```

Now, I know that it has to do with the indexing j, which is not valid for sliced variables. But I don't get why, because it is perfectly valid to run this in parallel.

Aside from the why, how could I implement this to run it in parallel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

M-lint shows you the following error:

> Fix the indexing. For a description of the indexing restrictions, see
>   [“Sliced Variables”](http://www.mathworks.com/help/distcomp/advanced-topics.html#bq_tcng-1) in the Parallel Computing Toolbox documentation.

Specifically the following requirement is not met:

> **Form of Indexing** — Within the list of indices for the variable, exactly one index involves the loop variable.

one way to workaround this is using a temporary array:

```
parfor i=1:1000
    %# ...

    tmp = ones(1,N);
    while j <= N && S > 1
        %# ...

        tmp(j) = S;
        j = j+1;
    end
    resultsOfRW(i,:) = tmp;
end
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried something similar, and failed. Apparently it's required that you declare 'tmp' within the parfor (and not before).

Comment: Ok, I got it working now. But when I run it and add some 'disp(\'now iteration i\')', I don't get parallel results. And my processor use is only 25% (on a quadcore)...

Comment: `tmp` is declared inside `parfor`. Other than that, I honestly don't know how MATLAB runs this in parallel under the hood.. Perhaps you can contact MathWorks for a support request, or wait for someone else here more familiar with parallel programming... (I know of @Edric who is active here on SO in MATLAB + PCT toolbox)

Comment: Thanks again! It's not of vital importance (I did the calculations in a serial manner already), just trying to get some experience with the parallel computing options in Matlab.